# More accuracy in neural network result with MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, neural-network

I tried to use a neural network to predict some data. I used the
MATLAB neural network fitting toolbox and I could predict some tests.
But the problem is the accuracy is not good enough for my results.
I tried to change the neuron numbers to change accuracy, but it was not good.

I wanted to change the trainer function, but I didn't find anything.
For example, I want to command MATLAB's toolbox to try to train until the accuracy is less than 0.1.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `net.trainParam.goal` to set the performance goal or increase `net.trainParam.epochs` to increase the maximum number of epochs to train.

Comment: ITNOA is performance goal the same as accuracy of network output result?